# Up and down arrow unicode font size issue

Tags: css, html, unicode

I have one of the most strangest problems that I have faced till today. I am trying to show up and down arrow in unicode in HTML. However, they are not same in size and color.

This is a small issue yet very irritating and stressful to me

```html
<div>&#708;</div>
<div>&#8964;</div>
```

I will be really grateful if somebody could help me. I've already wasted 5 hours behind this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the correct pair of arrows. Use `&#709;` entity for the corresponding down arrow.

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/73rqv02t/1/)

```html
<div>&#708;</div>
<div>&#709;</div>
```

If you're interested in filled arrows

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/73rqv02t/2/)

```html
<div>&#9650;</div>
<div>&#9660;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Tushar!! After 5 hours finally :D

Answer (score 0):

Well they are different. Its not a font size issue.
http://graphemica.com/%CB%84
http://graphemica.com/%E2%8C%84

You should use bootstraps glyphicons
http://jsfiddle.net/c9gp9a1w/

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

bootstrap
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons

Comment: glyphicon is best however if I use this as jquery html() function my main div stops getting click handlers :( probably suitable for a new question.

Comment: Are you trying to make the arrows change on click? You can do this with glyphicons. you can do something like:   $('#menu-toggle').click( function(){
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-right').toggleClass('glyphicon-arrow-left');
});

Comment: I am using jqxsplitter library and it has events on main button. If I keep span tag inside it and click on main button it never receives any event.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the matching pair.

&#708 matches with &#709.
While &#8964 matches with &#8963.